# Pathnames fail if they contain "\n"

Tags: python

I have a collection of files storing info on files used in web pages.

In the files they are in win7 format with single backslashes.
Each time it happens that the path string contains an 'n' following a single slash i.e. `"E:\_sorted\named\header1.py"`

the string can't be processed and gives such errors as:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.
```

I have tried to replace the `'\n'` occurrences with `'\\n'` but get the same result.

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

\n is an escape sequence for a new line.

To get python to ignore these you can make the string a raw string by putting a r before it. For example

```
x = "C:\files\new\abc.txt"
```

goes to

```
x = r"C:\files\new\abc.txt"
```

You will get the same issue with \t as this is the sequence for tab.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I found it worked okay if I changed the back-slashes to a forward-slashes.